# How to check input fields for emptiness in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, input

I have an input fields array, after clicking on the button, a check for emptiness will be performed, I wrote the code, but an error occurs: "Syntax error; value expected". Please tell me how to solve this problem?

```
public InputField[] InputFields; 

public void Done()
{
    if (InputFields[].Text.Length == string.Empty)
    {
        Debug.LogFormat("Empty!");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to loop through all the elements of your array

```
public InputField[] InputFields;

public void Done() {
    foreach (InputField inputField in InputFields) {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(inputField.text)) {
            Debug.LogFormat($"{inputField.name} field is Empty!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: And please tell me again how to make only one output if all fields are empty?

Comment: Could you be specific on what do you want to achieve by checking only if all fields are empty? you can edit you question or ask a new one if you are having an issue.

Comment: thanks for the help, I have already solved the problem